# How do I stop endless recursion when two objects reference each other?

Tags: javascript, java, recursion, computer-science

Let's say I want to make a deep copy of an object. I use recursion to traverse its properties. Now one of these properties can be an object. 
For example:

```
Person A
  Name: "Fred"
  Best Friend: Person B
```

Now if Person B is:

```
Person B
  Name: "Max"
  Best Friend: Person A
```

This would create an endless recursion. How could I avoid this endless loop?

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: You might look at the code from [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) ([public](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.27.0/source/internal/_clone.js) and [internal](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.27.0/source/clone.js) -- disclaimer: I'm an author) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/) ([public](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/cloneDeep.js) and [internal](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/.internal/baseClone.js)) for some hints.  The trick is to keep a map of everything already cloned and make reference to those clones instead of creating new ones.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the same sort of logic that [JSON.stringify](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-serializejsonobject) uses to avoid endless loops.

> 1. If state.[[Stack]] contains value, throw a TypeError exception because the structure is cyclical.

It keeps a stack of the parent objects being serialized. Every time the method to serialize a new value is called, the stack is examined to see if the value is already in the process of being serialized, and if it is, an error is thrown.

For your example, if you were going to make a copy of "Person A", the parent stack when considering how to copy the "Best Friend" property would be [Person A]. Going deeper, when serializing Person B's "Best Friend" property, the parent stack would be [Person A, Person B]. Upon seeing that the next item to serialize, Person B's "Best Friend" value, Person A, is already in the stack, throw an error.

Comment: Ideally, you might want more than just the ancestors but any other nodes in the object graph.  The first time you clone a node, you keep track of the result, and whenever else in the graph you need to clone something you already have, you don't do it again but return the copy.  Thus if `{foo: obj, bar: obj}` is cloned, you'll get `{foo: obj2, bar: obj2}` where `obj2` is a single clone of `obj`.  The ancestors track is necessary to avoid infinite recursion, but this technique is necessary for both object size and a similarity of behavior.